# Any idea whether TLS 1.3 works with .NET framework 4.7.1?

Tags: tls1.3, .net-4.7.1

Asking here to see whether .NET Framework 4.8 really needed for TLS 1.3 as the documentation is creating confusion. My existing app using .NET 4.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and the community provided some answers:
https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/4675#issuecomment-1233647865

One such answer:

> There is more than just the enum. to get TLS 1.3 callers of schannel need to call different API. If the "normal"/"legacy" API is used schannel will negotiate only up to 1.2.
>
> The only one way you can succeed while targeting 4.7 is to use actual 4.8 runtime on the new machines. 4.7 does not have the enum, but the None should still work. - wfurt Tomas Weinfurt

Note: I will update this answer if I have any further findings.